# Changing the receiving frequency of a cheap RC car

Tags: rf, antenna, remote-control

My kids both have a RC car and unfortunately they both work on the 27MhZ frequency range, which means they can't both play at the same time because of interference.

I opened up one of the two cars and fount out the emitter is using a 27.145MhZ crystal while the receiver has no crystal in sight, but an adjustable multi turn inductor in the antenna path.

Naïvely, I tried changing the crystal to a 40.685MhZ one and then turn the inductor until the car reacts. As it may be obvious to some of you, this did not work at all.

So, I went back to the bench and created a schematic of the receiver circuit board. From what I gathered during various searches, it's built around a RX2C / ATS302R IC or a very similar one as the pins connection match what is inside the [datasheet](http://hackedgadgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/RX_TX.pdf) for that IC. Note that the IC inside the toy has had its markings scratched to render them unreadable...

What's puzzling me is that the antenna parts values does not respect exactly what is inside that datasheet but rather are like this:

[image: Antenna circuit]

The L1 and L3 inductors are through hole parts with color rings on them like so :

- L1: Red, Red, Gold, Silver
- L3: Green, Blue, Gold, Silver

I thus believe they are 2.2µH and 5.6µH respectively.

This does not look like the simple RLC circuit I know about from my "initiation to electronics" textbook, but I'm not surprised at all.

That being said, do you think I could modify part(s) of this circuit to shift the frequency to 40MhZ? Like, for instance, add a resistor in parallel to R1 so that it gives an equivalent resistor with lower value, thus decreases the RLC constant and increases the frequency?

A few additional remarks:

- VCC is 4.8-6V, from a 4 AA batteries pack
- D1 is believed to be a 2.7V Zener diode
- C12 is an electrolytic capacitor whose value is printed on its side, rated 10V
- All resistor values match their marking and were confirmed with an ohmmeter.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers as to what I should be looking for or trying.

Comment: *crystal while the receiver has no crystal in sight* That means that the receiver is "wideband" meaning, it will receive anything close to 27 MHz. These type of receivers are too cheap and simple to work in the way that you want so your only option is to get toys with better receivers which have a "channel" setting switch so they're designed to work at the same time without interfering.

Comment: In this day and age if you want to do DIY RC projects go digital. An MCU and SPI packet radio like an nRF24 are comparable with high end hobby sets and in some cases interoperable.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a reverse engineering, modification, or repair question. Please be aware that such questions must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being discussed, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. Otherwise, the question is far too broad. More information can be found here: [Is asking how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Comment: Thank your for your comment. 
The device is functioning properly and this is not a repair question. To me it seems clear from my description that I'm asking for help about changing the value of the receiving frequency. I don't think it's overly broad, and I do understand a fair bit about RLC oscillators.
In your opinion, what should I change in the question above?

Answer (score 0):

Given this is the ONLY RF circuit, but needing only 100 foot range, we can trace out the circulating-RF-resonance-path. I think its

C4 -- L3 -- Cemitter_base -- C5

and

C4 -- L3 -- C2 -- L2||C3 -- C6

but note the series LC to the antenna. With the car's antenna out in free-space.

C3+R2 likely are the super-regenerative quenching-oscillation time constant, thus C3 is
a timing capacitor for 100,000 Hz explore-the-RF-power-level behavior.

Looks like there are THREE resonant LC circuits: 2 of series (L3,C4 and L1,C1) and 1 of parallel (L2,C3).

The Q of L3,R1 (5.6uH at 30MHz => Z of ~~1,000 ohm, and 560 ohms) is about 1 or 2, so no frequency selection occurring in the emitter.

If C4 is a huge value, then a possible LC resonance is the L3,C2.